# What is meaning of 0/cache in redis://localhost:6379/0/cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

While adding redis as my cache store in Rails app,

i added the redis url as `redis://localhost:6379/0/cache`.

What is the meaning of `0/cache` in the redis URL?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may configure redis to use many databases.

The `0` means you are using the first of them (id=0).
The `cache` is the namespace of the database.

Depending on where you set this url, you are actually telling to use redis caching and values will be saved/retrieved etc from the database `0` and namespace `cache`.

Comment: Tell me one more thing. How many databases are there exist by default?

Comment: I tested this with redis-rails (redis-store for Rails), and there's no 'cache' namespace. I had to set a namespace through the namespace option like so: `config.cache_store = :redis_store, 'redis://localhost:6379/0', { expires_in: 60.minutes, namespace: "#{Rails.env}:cache" }`